# Matching hashes using regex, but not when they are part of an url

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling with a regex in javascript that needs the text after # to the first word boundary, but not match it if it is part of an url. So

#test - should match test
sometext#test2 - should match test2
xx moretext#test3 - should match test3
http://test.com#tab1 - should not match tab1

I am replacing the text after the hash with a link (but not the hash character itself). There can be more than one hash in the text, and it should match them all (I guess I should use /g for that).

Matching the part after the hash is quite easy: /#\b(.+?)\b/g, but not matching it if the string itself starts with "http" is something I cannot solve. I should probably use a negative look-around, but I am having problems getting my head around that.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it *have* to be a regular expression? Because, a quick check suggests that basic string functions (and `if`) should be able to do what you need? Albeit I'm not sure it'd be particular quick, but then again: neither is regex, really.

Comment: A previous version used that, but was very slow (sometimes it had to parse hundreds of comments, which caused older computers to come to a grinding halt). That's why I chose to switch to a regex.

Comment: That's understandable, though I'm curious as to the volume of work you were asking it to do; having said that a quick (and non-optimised) [JS Fiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9TFXg/1/)) seems to vary between 3 and 8ms; so I can imagine for 'hundreds' it became quite slow quite quickly). Incidentally, I'd definitely be interested in a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/), should you be able to post one?

Comment: No, not at the moment. The previous solution was on a different site that is not online anymore. My new version uses regex already, and is a lot faster. The only problem is that it scrambles urls with hashes. 

If the new regex would make it very slow, then your solution would be a nice alternative!

Comment: In the end I used a solution that was derived from your JS fiddle. Thanks for that! It probably can be made more efficient, but it parses 200 comments in about 500ms, which is good enough for me.

If you could add your comment as a solution, I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As regex is, often (if not always), quite expensive to use, I'd suggest using basic string, and array, methods to determine whether a given set of characters represents an URL (though I'm assuming that all URLS will start with the `http` string):

```
$('ul li').each(
    function() {
        var t = $(this).text(),
            words = t.split(/\s+/),
            foundHashes = [],
            word = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
            word = words[i];
            if (word.indexOf('http') == -1 && word.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
                var match = word.substring(word.indexOf('#') + 1);
                foundHashes.push(match);
            }
        }
        // the following just shows what, if anything, was found
        // and can definitely be safely omitted
        if (foundHashes.length) {
            var newSpan = $('<span />', {
                'class': 'matchedWords'
            }).text(foundHashes.join(', ')).appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo (with some timing information printed to the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9TFXg/1/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- 'Vanilla' JavaScript

  - [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: Thanks! I used this solution, and it takes about 500 ms for 200 comments, and that is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex using a negative lookahead instead since JS doesn't support lookbehinds:

```
/^(?!http:\/\/).*#\b(.+?)\b/
```

You may want to check for `www` too, depending on your conditions.

**Edit:** Then you can do this:

```
str = str.replace(re.exec(str)[1], 'replaced!');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7c79/2/

**Edit 2:** Sometimes a regex alone is not the way to go if it gets too complicated. Try a different approach:

```
var txt = "asdfgh http://asdf#test1 #test2 woot#test3";

function replaceHashWords(str, rep) {
  var isUrl = /^http/.test(str), result = [];
  !isUrl && str.replace(/#\b(.+?)\b/g, function(a,b){ result.push(b); });
  return str.replace((new RegExp('('+ result.join('|') +')','g')), rep);
}

alert(replaceHashWords(txt, 'replaced!')); 
// asdfgh http://asdf#replaced! #replaced! woot#replaced!
```

Comment: Ah, that one is getting in the right direction, but it also  matches whitespace (see: http://jsfiddle.net/j7c79/3/) and matches just one hash tag per string...

Comment: Sometimes a regex alone is not the way to go if it get too complicated. Try a different approach, see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, that probably will be the best approach (which was also suggested by others). Your current solution also matches the "url hashes", which it should not, but I will probably be able to figure that one out myself. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I didn't fully understand your requirements tho... In any case you could try splitting the string by spaces and then compare each chunk individually against the first regex I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This would require a lookbehind, something sadly lacking from JavaScript's capabilities.

However, if your subject string is some HTML and those URLs are in `href` attributes, you can create a document out of it and search for text nodes, only replacing their `nodeValue`s instead of the whole HTML string.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it would be quite cumbersome to parse all the nodes of hundreds of comments (it is something that runs on the comment section of my site). Or am I mistaken?